# Any way to make a drive(ZFS) unbootable?

Tags: freebsd, hard-disk, zfs, freenas

Lets say you can't access the bios to change the boot order of a drive, How would you go about booting from a particular drive.

Is it possible to make every other drive 'unbootable' and thus making the remaining drive the only way for the computer to boot? Or is this scenario impossible to solve?

---

**Edit** - More about the situation

So I've had this laptop for awhile where the screen and the HDMI port of the laptop was not working. I wanted to put it to use and make it into a NAS so I flashed a copy of freenas to a USB drive using my desktop machine(using a vm) and plugged it into my laptop(no internal hard drive) and got it to work. Then i added a external hard drive to the laptop and am using it happily :)

But i wanted to check if I take the external drive out of the enclosure and add it inside my laptop, if that would work. But sadly it didn't and I'm sure it's because the laptop is trying to boot from the internal hard drive.

---

Thanks in advance for any advice :)

Comment: Just to be clear. there is a zpool on the internal drive and you want to make it unbootable?

Comment: @airhuff yeah..

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the bootfs field for the pool to "none".

`sudo zpool set bootfs=none [pool name]`

To be certain of what it currently set to so you can set it back later, run:

`sudo zpool get bootfs [pool name]`

Also note that "pool name" is optional if you only have one pool.

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know :)